# Disable review on rollbacks by the user whose change is being rolled back

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, documentation, rollbacks, documentation-review

I found [this rollback](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/106287) of one of my recent changes in the dashboard, and I found out, a bit to my surprise, that *I could reject it.*

[image: Screenshot showing the Reject button]

Why am I allowed to do this? I *shouldn't* be able to do this.

Obviously silver tag badge holders would be able to, because they're basically God in their Documentation tags anyway, but I don't have a silver tag badge.

Comment: ...Are you both "Some Person" *and* "RamenChef" then?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan No. Some Person made a change, then RamenChef rolled it back.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan though it is hard to tell us apart in real life :P

Comment: Some Person by day, Ramen Chef by night, always makin' Arrays.

Comment: Having never used this, I wonder why this can't just a feature instead of a bug.  You can click [delete] if you posted a question or answer that did not turn out well.  You can click [rollback] when you aren't happy about an edit.  What do you do when you regret a proposed change?  Well, click it.  Only thing you can do wrong is not trying it :)

Comment: @HansPassant this is like someone else deleting your question. You can’t undelete it without approval (right?).

Comment: Erm, it is not "someone else".  He wants to stop himself from deleting his own proposal.  I don't get it either, maybe his mouse has a life of its own :)

Comment: @HansPassant actually, Some Person made a change, and RamenChef proposed a change rolling it back to the version prior to Some Person's proposal. Some Person doesn't think that they should be able to reject the rollback, because they are the Some Person one who submitted the version being rolled back. This would more similarly be compared to having your own post deleted by a moderator, and being allowed to unilaterally undelete said post.

Comment: Why *shouldn't* you have a say on a proposed change to something you did?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan and Lambdas. (Though honestly, just look at my profile. It explains why I said it.)

Comment: `status-declined` because Documentation is gone.

Comment: @MartijnPieters why close this again?

Comment: @StephenLeppik: why ask me, I didn't close it. But the close reason *does* apply, now that docs is gone.

Comment: @MartijnPieters isn't that close reason for bugs, though?

Comment: @StephenLeppik: it's applicable here too, the original circumstances that prompted your feature request no longer exist.